# SSRS doesn't display all the data when toggle option is used (only one page for display ~1000 rows)

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have issue in SSRS where I have a report for some indicators, but
underneath some of the indicators I want to display detailed info rows for that indicator. Because of that I used toggle option so I don't see rows of detailed info rows unless I need them. And everything is on this one page which is ok.

But issue comes in a case where there is almost 2000 rows for detailed info for certain indicator and when I expand tablix I don't see all the data but only 1400 rows for example and don't see anything what was after that tablix in the report.

When I try to display data without toggling option there is about 50+ pages instead of only 2 (I think SSRS want's all tablix's content to be on 1 page which in this case can't be done and everything else on the rest).

Is there a solution for this?

I tired grouping of data and putting option page break after new group but no luck.

Comment: Are you *really* still using SQL Server 2008? It's been *completely* unsupported for well over 3 years. Ypu *really* need to get your instance upgraded and onto a supported version.

Comment: It's not sql server 2008 but ruther ssrs 3. Anyhow, do you have any concrete advice?

Comment: What is "ssrs 3" If you're not using SQL Server 2008, why have you tagged [[tag:ssrs-2008]]?

Comment: SSRS 3 is from 2012 sp4, for me it seems like an issue even from 2008 that came to 2012 as well.

Comment: SSRS 2012 is also completely unsupported, so you should be looking at the upgrade paths for that too.

Comment: I cant upgrade since it is companies policy on what they want to use. 

Does later versions of ssrs don't have this limitation?

Comment: I have never seen the limitation you are talking about, and I used 2012 for almost the entirety of it's lifecycle.

Comment: For me it's weird to have only diplay up to 1200 rows (as it comes to an end of the first page) but if there is no toggle checked it does display all the rows and renders it as 50+ pages without any issue.